# How to convert Span<byte> to ASCII string?

Tags: c#

I can convert byte array to ASCII string in C# by `Encoding.ASCII.Getstring()` method.

But I don't know how to convert Span to String.

Added I want to use `Span<byte>.ToArray()`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So why not convert the span to an array and then to a string using the methods you've mentioned?

Comment: @John I just want to write a simple code.

Comment: @CodeRed Until now, I used Span<T>.ToArray() Method.

Comment: @JohanP new string(Span<T>) does not exist in .NetFramework.

Comment: OP: What do you consider to be simple? If you mean you want a `GetString` method that simply takes a `Span<byte>`, I don't think that exists yet.

Comment: @John Okay. Thank you.

Comment: Make your *simple code* helper method, and be done with it. (knowing this will be one or more allocations). There is no BCL method to do this as yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Encoding.GetString` does not accept `Span<byte>`.

But you can create a [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static class EncodingExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this Encoding encoding, Span<byte> source)
    {
        //naive way using ToArray, but possible to improve when needed
        return encoding.GetString(source.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you are able to call:

```
var foo = new Span<byte>();
var bar = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(foo);
```

Comment: GetString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes) has been added in the meanwhile.