# Is there any way to bind the 2 for loops in one for loop in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

- The code where it reads Messages from MCU and stores them in an array of 8 bytes[0]~[7],
- specifically storing the first 4 elements in the first half, indexes [0] ~[3], and the next four elements in the next half, indexes [4] ~[7]
- Is there any easier way to do it?

```
halfbytelength = 4;
bytelength =8;

case 0:

 for (index = 0; index <halfbytelength; index += 1)
 {
    Array1[index] = msg[index];
 }
 for (index = halfbytelength; index < bytelength; index += 1)
 {
   Array2[index - halfbytelength] = msg[index];
 }
 MainArray[0] = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Array1);
 MainArray[1] = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Array2);
```

Comment: What exactly changes for each case, if the loops in each case have the same syntax? Is it which `MainArray` indices to populate? Perhaps the whole switch case could be simplified as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no need to write the loop to copy bytes yourself. You could for example use spans to slice the array.

```
var array1 = msg.AsSpan().Slice(0, 4).ToArray();
var array2 = msg.AsSpan().Slice(4, 4).ToArray();
```

I would say that it is significantly easier to read. Or [add an extension method to convert a span to string directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054422/how-to-convert-spanbyte-to-ascii-string).

Or you could use Array.Copy

```
Array.Copy(msg, 0, array1, 0, 4);
Array.Copy(msg, 4, array2, 0, 4);
```

But I find that less easy to read.

With regards to performance I would not expect a huge difference. I would expect converting the array to a string to take more time than copying a few bytes. But any method that avoid allocations might have some advantage if it is run in a tight loop.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH ("Beautiful Mind" one of my favourite movie to date)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `bytelength` stays **even**, you can do the following to **replace your 2 loops with 1**:

```
for (int index = 0; index < halfbytelength; ++index)
{
    Array1[index] = msg[index];
    Array2[index] = msg[index + halfbytelength];
}
```

**Note:** as @JeremyLakeman commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541249/is-there-any-way-to-bind-the-2-for-loops-in-one-for-loop-in-c-sharp/72541305#comment128143260_72541305), using [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0) might be faster.
Your code will also be shorter (1 line per array, with no loops).
(assuming that `msg`,`Array1`,`Array2` are of array type - which you didn't specify in your question).

Comment: Though calling `Array.Copy` may be faster.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman you are probably right. I tried to stick to the question about uniting the loops.